# Creating HTML/PHP Form to allow users upload basic files on my shared GoDaddy Hosting

Tags: php, forms, multipartform-data

I am using the following HTML form to upload a simple image file on GoDaddy Shared Linux PHP Hosting:

```
<form action="./upload_ar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p>
      <label for="file">Select a file:</label> <input type="file" name="userfile" id="file"> <br />
      <button>Upload File</button>
   <p>
</form>
```

The HTML form above then calls the following PHP script:

```
<?php
   // Configuration - Your Options
      $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png', '.txt'); // These will be the types of file that will pass the validation.
      $max_filesize = 524288; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
      $upload_path = 'files/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).

   $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
   $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

   // Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
   if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
      die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

   // Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
   if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
      die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

   // Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
   if(!is_writable($upload_path))
      die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

   // Upload the file to your specified path.
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
         echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="' . $upload_path . $filename . '" title="Your File">here</a>'; // It worked.
      else
         echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.'; // It failed :(.

?>
```

I have already create the folder and set the permission to '777'. However, when I upload a file, I get this error message:

**There was an error during the file upload. Please try again.**

The error above corresponds to the last line of PHP script. I have no idea why it keeps failing.

Could you please help?

Comment: Can you confirm that the file in the uploads/ directory doesn't already exist?

Comment: @tehlulz: Confirmed. The directory is completely empty.

Comment: Also make sure that upload_max_filesize post_max_size aren't set lower. They will override the settings in your php script.

Comment: I suggest checking the server settings.

Your code 100% works on my local server.

Comment: @tehlulz: I am trying to upload a test file with 1KB size. However, I added php.ini file and set the upload_max_filesize=32M and post_max_size=32M

Comment: @tehlulz: I cannot check the server... it is GoDaddy shared hosting server. I do not have access to the server settings.

Comment: I guess people don't like GoDaddy... I am surprised no one is giving a solid answer on this simple task...

Comment: A simple phpinfo() will produce that information I mentioned.

Comment: @tehlulz: I just double checked the current PHP environment using phpinfo() and can confirm that upload_max_filiesize is set to 2M and post_max_size is set to 8M. The test file I want to upload is 1K.

Comment: I am surprise no one replied this thread.